# Bug identification: how to identify this bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this cast/shed skin from molting in my house:

[image: Front of shed skin]

[image: Back of shed skin]

The house is in the countryside by the beach in Portugal with a temperate and humid climate and mostly pine trees and eucalyptus. Humidity is 84% and temperature around 21ºC indoors. The size is 1-2 cm.

From [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/981655) it looks like a beetle. I also tried [InsectIdentification.org](https://www.insectidentification.org/bugfinder.asp) but it's limited to US, Canada, and Mexico.

Can anyone identify the cast skin? And does such bug identification require an expert or can an amateur use some resources to do it?

Comment: It is not a cast skin, as adults do not molt, and this is an adult beetle. You can tell because it has elytra (forewings), and only adults have them. It reminds me of a Scarab.

Comment: I can't see the forewings, but I trust your judgment! Would you like to write an answer? And what resources would you recommend for a newbie to identify bugs?

Comment: Trying to identify this specimen much past family (and I agree with @Karl WRT that) might not be possible, as the head appears to be missing; in addition, this appears to be the remains of a spider's meal (there are obvious fibers -- probably silk -- visible in both photographs).